# Crystal Reports Xi - Sorting a CrossTab Report by a Summary Field

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

So I have a simple crosstab report that calculates number of sales in the columns, and the rows are each office. The last column on the right is a total column, which contains a summary field (via a count of the identity field) that adds up the total number of sales per office.

How can I sort the crosstab data so the office with the most sales is the top row, and the rest in order under it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:  Right-click on the crosstab. Go into the **Group Sort Expert** menu. There you will see options to display the top N rows, Sort All by the aggregate of a field of your choice, etc.

(I'm using Crystal XI. If your version is different, this may not work exactly)

Comment: the group sort expert option is grayed out since i'm not sorting by anything.

Comment: I'm referring to the group sort expert in the Crosstab itself, NOT the report's group sort.  I made a dummy report without any groupings, added a crosstab, and was able to access it.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to another CR feature (I've been using it since v4.5).